# Enabling Network on VirtualBox with Mobile Broadband

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox

I have set up a Windows7 VM on Virtual Box. Host OS is Ubuntu Oneiric. I am connected to internet on host OS using mobile connection. I want to use this connection on my VM as well. But I am unable to set up network on Virtual Box.

I googled for the solution. But most of them were either for Wireless or for wired connection. I tried few of them but in vain.

I am a newbie and don't have much idea how to do this. Please help me so that I can connect my VM to the host OS network.

My current network settings are as follows.

```
$ ifconfig
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:03:73:6c:45:17  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:46 Base address:0x2000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:322 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:322 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:35653 (35.6 KB)  TX bytes:35653 (35.6 KB)

ppp0  Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:10.134.80.235  P-t-P:10.6.6.6  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:15072 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14818 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:14028308 (14.0 MB)  TX bytes:1659735 (1.6 MB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I changed the network configuration on Virtual Box.

The configuration which enabled networking on guest OS is below.

```
Attached to:     NAT
Adapter Type:    Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)
Promiscous Mode: Allow VMs
Cable Connected: Yes
```

The solution which Parth gave was correct. Its just that Cable Connected was disabled in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

well, does your host os internet connection is working ? if it is working well then you dont need to establish special configuration. Just enable NAT !

As you have mentioned you are using virtual box, then in virtual box window -> select the guest os -> settings -> Network -> Attached to NAT !

Comment: Yes... my host os connection is working fine. NAT is also enabled. But still VM is not connected to network!